# Any idea what’s going on here with this subway tile?

Tags: shower, tile, crack

Tile was installed a few weeks ago. These hairline cracks formed after grouting.  You can’t feel the cracks on the face of the tile. There has been no water run in the shower. [image]Any ideas.

Comment: A tile expert will hopefully weigh in, but that looks to me like "crazing" that was probably always there but has been highlighted by the dark grout. Check your uninstalled tiles and see if they are also crazed. Maybe a grout remover and hard brushwork can diminish the look. Or maybe you call it art and have done with it.

Comment: Doesn't look like a very good grouting job, so this may be part of the problem. Look at the amount of grout left around the edges of the tile.

Comment: It looks like stress cracks in the glaze. I have seen this with clay tile. As the mortar dries or hydrates in my cases it was a very thin glaze. Evidence of this is the glaze is not completely sealing the tile notice the black leaching into the edges. A inexpensive tile choice has been the root cause for me. Seal it really well or remove and start over.